ImageMagick conversion is creating transparent regions where it shouldn't
I have a number of .png files - AI generated.  I would like to convert these to .svg format.  My routine works well in a lot of cases but (I think with darker images) it has a habit of creating transparent regions 'inside' the object in the image - where the object is darkest.
The desired behaviour is that the object in the image be isolated, all regions 'outside' should be made transparent and the object itself be opaque in the resultant .svg file.
This is what I have tried
using ImageMagick;
using OpenCvSharp;

namespace SvgShared
{
    public class ImageToSvgConverter
    {
        private const long MaxOutputFileSize = 750 * 1024; // Target file size in bytes
        private const double InitialScaleFactor = 1;
        private const double ScaleAdjustmentFactor = 0.9;

        public void ConvertImageToSvg(string imagePath, string svgOutputPath)
        {
            try
            {
                double scale = InitialScaleFactor;
                long outputFileSize = long.MaxValue;

                do
                {
                    // Load the image using OpenCV
                    using (var src = new Mat(imagePath, ImreadModes.Color))
                    {
                        // Resize the image
                        using (var resizedSrc = new Mat())
                        {
                            Cv2.Resize(src, resizedSrc, new Size(), scale, scale, InterpolationFlags.Linear);

                            // Create a mask for the foreground
                            using (var mask = new Mat())
                            {
                                CreateForegroundMask(resizedSrc, mask);

                                // Apply the mask to the image
                                using (var masked = new Mat())
                                {
                                    resizedSrc.CopyTo(masked, mask);

                                    // Convert to BGRA (to support transparency)
                                    using (var result = new Mat())
                                    {
                                        Cv2.CvtColor(masked, result, ColorConversionCodes.BGR2BGRA);

                                        // Set all black pixels to transparent
                                        for (int y = 0; y < result.Rows; y++)
                                        {
                                            for (int x = 0; x < result.Cols; x++)
                                            {
                                                Vec4b color = result.At<Vec4b>(y, x);
                                                if (color[0] == 0 && color[1] == 0 && color[2] == 0)
                                                {
                                                    result.Set(y, x, new Vec4b(0, 0, 0, 0));
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }

                                        // Convert result back to MagickImage
                                        var resultBytes = result.ToBytes(".png");
                                        using (var resultImage = new MagickImage(resultBytes))
                                        {
                                            // Set the format to SVG
                                            resultImage.Format = MagickFormat.Svg;

                                            // Write the image to a temporary SVG file
                                            string tempSvgPath = Path.GetTempFileName();
                                            resultImage.Write(tempSvgPath);

                                            // Get the file size of the temporary SVG file
                                            outputFileSize = new FileInfo(tempSvgPath).Length;

                                            // If the file size is within the target range, move the temp file to the output path
                                            if (outputFileSize <= MaxOutputFileSize)
                                            {
                                                File.Move(tempSvgPath, svgOutputPath, true);
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                // Adjust the scale factor for the next iteration
                                                scale *= ScaleAdjustmentFactor;
                                                File.Delete(tempSvgPath);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } while (outputFileSize > MaxOutputFileSize);

                Console.WriteLine("Conversion successful!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred during conversion: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        private void CreateForegroundMask(Mat src, Mat mask)
        {
            // Convert the image to grayscale
            using (var gray = new Mat())
            {
                Cv2.CvtColor(src, gray, ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY);

                // Use Otsu's threshold to create a binary mask
                using (var binary = new Mat())
                {
                    Cv2.Threshold(gray, binary, 0, 255, ThresholdTypes.BinaryInv | ThresholdTypes.Otsu);

                    // Find contours
                    Cv2.FindContours(binary, out var contours, out _, RetrievalModes.External, ContourApproximationModes.ApproxSimple);

                    // Initialize mask
                    mask.Create(src.Size(), MatType.CV_8UC1);
                    mask.SetTo(Scalar.Black);

                    // Draw contours on the mask
                    foreach (var contour in contours)
                    {
                        Cv2.DrawContours(mask, new[] { contour }, -1, Scalar.White, -1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class MatExtensions
    {
        public static MagickImage ToMagickImage(this Mat mat)
        {
            var data = mat.ToBytes(".png");
            return new MagickImage(data);
        }
    }
}

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
